# Menu Fullpage.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, nav, fullpage.js

I have a question for you, i try to make a new project with fullpage.js.

But, my question is, how to make a menu, i try with :

Problem is, when i click for example on porfolio, it's ok, i'm on the second slide, but.. isn't possible for me to click on another tab

(HTML Part)

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li data-menuanchor="Accueil"><a href="#Acc">Accueil</a></li>
        <li data-menuanchor="PortFolio"><a href="#Port">PortFolio</a></li>
        <li data-menuanchor="Contact"><a href="#Con">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

and for JS part :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#fullpage').fullpage({
            sectionsColor: ['', '#4BBFC3', '#7BAABE', 'whitesmoke', '#000'], 
            anchors: ['Accueil', 'PortFolio', 'Contact'],

        });
        $.fn.fullpage.setScrollingSpeed(1500);
    });
</script>
```

Thank for helping :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ouuups ! I'm sorry to create this post for nothing.. I find the solution.

The solution was to, change in my CSS file.

with, this configuration :

```css
#menu li {
 display:inline-block;
 margin: 10px;
 color: #000;
 background:#fff;
 background: rgba(255,255,255, 0.5);
 -webkit-border-radius: 4px; 
            border-radius: 4px; 
}
#menu li.active{
 background:#666;
 background: rgba(0,0,0, 0.5);
 color: #fff;
}
#menu li a{
 text-decoration:none;
 color: #000;
}
#menu li.active a:hover{
 color: #000;
}
#menu li:hover{
 background: rgba(255,255,255, 0.8);
}
#menu li a,
#menu li.active a{
 padding: 9px 18px;
 display:block;
}
#menu li.active a{
 color: #fff;
}
#menu{
 position:fixed;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 height: 40px;
 z-index: 70;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 0;
 margin:0;
}
```